# Eiffel: a way to display assertion violation on runtime of executable

Tags: eiffel

As I have the choice on **finalizing a project to keep assertions**, I'd think that assertion violation would be shown or **displayed on console (hopefully on stderr on linux)**. What would be the proper way to do such, like seems that I have to add it or enable something to get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything additional (at least, I've never had to). The assertion violation will result in a stack trace to stderr.

Comment: dont have any with finalize from estudio and then run executable. But stops when running into estudio